# Complete azure novice - what is it and how do I check if my changes were committed

Tags: c#, azure

I am a complete newbie to Azure, my understanding of it: It is a online database.

I have inherited the following code:

```
CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(
                CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("StorageConnectionString"));

CloudTableClient tableClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudTableClient();

table = tableClient.GetTableReference(
        Convert.ToString(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AzureTable"]));

table.CreateIfNotExists();
```

Now what I am confused about is:

```
1. Where do I log in to see if the table is created (if the value for AzureTable is not created?)
2. I have a MSDN subscription, is this all I need to connect to/use Azure?
```

Thanks,
Andrew

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `table.CreateIfNotExists` Returns a boolean value if the table was successfully created. [MSDN Link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.table.cloudtable.createifnotexists.aspx)

   1b. You can use a convenience tool such as Azure Storage Explorer [CodePlex Link](http://azurestorageexplorer.codeplex.com/) to view all the tables as well as all the rows.
2. An MSDN subscription is all you need, depending on the level (premium, ultimate etc) will determine how much credit you have to spend on all the Azure services; You can see this amount and remaining amount by clicking on green "Credit Status" button on the portal once you have logged in.

The MSDN accounts by default have a spending limit so don't worry, it won't charge your card, only your services will be suspended till the next billing period. A recent change has been implemented where if you shutdown some of your services they don't incur any running costs and save you some MSDN credits.

Comment: Can you give me the Portal link?

Answer (score 1):

I like [AzureXplorer](http://clumsyleaf.com/products/azurexplorer) to see the contents of the storages (blobs, tables, queues).

Maybe it can be useful for you.